# SQL - Selecting a value from conditional joins without UNION

Tags: sql

### Setup

```
create table things ( `t1_id` int, `t2_id` int);
insert into things (`t1_id`, `t2_id`)
values ( NULL, 1), (NULL, 2), (1, NULL),(2,NULL);

create table type_1 (`id` int, `name` TEXT);
insert into type_1 (`id`, `name`)
values (1, 'name 1'), (2, 'name2');

create table type_2 (`id` int, `name` TEXT);
insert into type_2 (`id`, `name`)
values (1, 'name 3'), (2, 'name4');
```

### Query

```
select coalesce (t1.name, t2.name) as name
from things
join type_1 as t1 on things.t1_id IS NOT NULL AND things.t1_id = t1.id
join type_2 as t2 on things.t2_id IS NOT NULL AND things.t2_id = t2.id
group by name
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfce11/7

I have what I've set out in the fiddle working with UNION, but in reality the rest of the query is expensive and the union doubled this - I'll probably need to do this for a second column too (`name2` from type_3 and type_4 could be in this example, things would always have either t1_id or t2_id and either t3_id or t4_id - I'm assuming the same solution would work).

I'm looking for `name` to be selected from one table or another depending on whether the relevant column in 'things' is null.. I could use a 'type' column in things to differentiate if it would be better.

The fiddle should return all 4 names.

Comment: There is no `UNION` in your query. You are inner joining t1 and t2, but a thing cannot match t1 and t2 at the same time, so you get no results. Convert the inner joins to left outer joins and you are done, I'd say.

Comment: thanks, I meant that I had it working with union, but needed it without.. 
left outer join might work, can't believe I didn't try it. Thanks!

Comment: Okay. I don't see, though, why `UNION` should be worse. Looks fine to me. `select name from type_1 where id in (select t1_id from things) union all select name from type_2 where id in (select t2_id from things)`.

Comment: I've posted both queries in an answer. You can look at the explain plan or just test them in order to decide for one.

Comment: strange, in my testing a 15 sec query ran for 2 mins with the union solution. Left Outer join looks great

Comment: With primary and foreign keys intact I assume there to be indexes on `things(t1_id)`, `things(t2_id)`, `type_1(id)`, and `type2(id)`. So, I am surprised as well. Both queries should be about equally fast in my opinion.

Comment: On a side note: When asking SQL questions, you should always tag the request with the DBMS you are using in order to get appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inner joining t1 and t2, but a thing cannot match t1 and t2 at the same time, so you get no results.

### Join query

```
select distinct coalesce (t1.name, t2.name) as name
from things
left join type_1 as t1 on things.t1_id = t1.id
left join type_2 as t2 on things.t2_id = t2.id;
```

### Union query

```
select name from type_1 where id in (select t1_id from things)
union
select name from type_2 where id in (select t2_id from things);
```

Both queries do the same thing. They give you all distinct names that are referenced in the things table.